# Touch events with a bar graph

Tags: ios, objective-c

I created a bar graph. If you tap on an individual bar, it will create a new UIView displaying some information.

I want to be able to drag my finger across the bars and have that info view to pop up.

How can I handle that type of touch events? Its not a press, but when the touch just enters the bar's area?

Each bar is a UIView with a UIControl to handle the touch event:

```
UIControl *control = [[UIControl alloc] init];
control.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = FALSE;
[control addTarget:self action:@selector(tapDetected:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[barView addSubview:control];

[barView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[control]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(control)]];
[barView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[control]|" options:0 metrics:nil views:NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(control)]];
```

I tried changing the `forControlEvents:` to `UIControlEventTouchDown` but is acting the same as `UIControlEventTouchUpInside`.

Answer (score 0):

`UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` should do what you're looking for. From the UIControl Class Reference:

> `UIControlEventTouchDragEnter` 
>   An event where a finger is dragged into
>   the bounds of the control.
> Available in iOS 2.0 and later.
> Declared in
>   UIControl.h.

**EDIT**
Of course the other thing that's probably causing problems is that you're instantiating `UIControl` objects directly, which you're not supposed to do. From the [`UIControl` Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> You cannot use the `UIControl` class directly to instantiate controls.
>   It instead defines the common interface and behavioral structure for
>   all its subclasses.
>
> The main role of `UIControl` is to define an interface and base
>   implementation for preparing action messages and initially dispatching
>   them to their targets when certain events occur.

Try using `UIButton` instead, with properties appropriately set to make their behaviour less button-ish, and see if your events get fired.

Comment: I can't get this to fire on any type of touch or drag.